# How do I get the "highlighted" status of a photo?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In the following screenshot, one of the images (top right) is "highlighted". How do I get this status programmatically?

[image: Facebook photos]

Answer (score 3):

You can use
 `[pageid]?fields=posts.fields(timeline_visibility)` ,

The return data wil have a field `"timeline_visibility" : "starred"`

But its only works for facebook pages, when i tried to get for my timeline

```
[userid]?fields=id,name,posts.fields(timeline_visibility)
```

return value is `"timeline_visibility": "no timeline unit for this post"`